# PHP GD - image damaged when using imagettftext()

Tags: php, gd, imagettftext

I'am using PHP 7.4, with Symfony 5.2, memory_limit = 1024M in php.ini

I implement an API which put a quote in an image, using **imagettftext()** method.

My problem is that **the image is damaged**. It seems to be because of the length of the text.

When the text is short, the result is ok:
[image ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQQCO.jpg)
When the text is longer, the image is damaged (color spots appear):
[image damaged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLjgf.jpg)

**Here is my code:**

```
private function createResource(string $imageContent, array $quote)
   {
      $image = \imagecreatefromstring($imageContent);

      $heigh = \imagesy($image);
      $width = \imagesx($image);

      $text = $quote['quote'];

      $charsArray = \str_split($text, 1);
      $charsTotalNb = \count($charsArray);
      $charsNbPerLine = (int) floor(($width - 50) / 10);
      $lineNb = (int) ceil($charsTotalNb / $charsNbPerLine);

      $text = \wordwrap($text, $charsNbPerLine, "|", \false);
      $quoteHeigh = 60 + $lineNb * 25;
      
      $card = \imagecreatetruecolor($width, $heigh + $quoteHeigh);
      
      $black = \imagecolorallocate($card, 0, 0, 0);
      $white = imagecolorallocate($card, 255, 255, 255);
      
      \imagefill($card, 0, 0, $black);
      \imagecopymerge($card, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $heigh, $quoteHeigh);
      \imagedestroy($image);
      
      $font = __DIR__ . '/../../public/fonts/Averia_Serif_Libre.ttf';
      
      \imagettftext($card, 15, 0, 25, $heigh + 30, $white, $font, $text);
      
      $author = $quote['author'];
      if (empty($author)) {
        $author = 'Anonymous';
      }
      
      \imagettftext(
         $card,
         12,
         0,
         (int) $width/2,
         $heigh + 40 + $lineNb * 25,
         $white,
         $font,
         '-' . $author . '-'
         );

      for ($i = 0 ; $i < 7 ; $i++ ) { 
         \imageline($card, 0 + $i, 0 + $i, 0 + $i , \imagesy($card), $black);
         \imageline($card, 0, 0 + $i, \imagesx($card) , 0 + $i, $black);
         \imageline($card, \imagesx($card) - $i, 0, \imagesx($card) - $i, \imagesy($card), $black);
      }

      if (empty(\get_resource_type($card))) {
         throw new Exception("Error Processing Request in CardService::createCard()");
      }

      return $card;
}
```

**How fix my problem ?** How to remedy the deterioration of the cat's image?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: There is an error in the line $text = \wordwrap($text, $charsNbPerLine, "|", \false); I forgot an edition, it's in fact: $text = \wordwrap($text, $charsNbPerLine, "\n|", \false);

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem in my code :

The following line is wrong because of the last argument :

```
\imagecopymerge($card, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $heigh, $quoteHeigh);
```

The correction is :

````
\imagecopymerge($card, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $heigh, 100);
```
````